# Google Maps logo attribution policy

Tags: google-maps

The automatically generated Google logo is just partially visible because of the mobile app interface elements.
Can I remove the automatically generated Google logo in order to reintroduce it in a visible form and fix it in the other part of the screen. Doesn't it violate the usage policy?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terms of use (legal issues) not coding

Comment: Short answer: you can not. It violates the google’s usage policy.